# Suggested method for handling lifetime of "remoting proxy objects"

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I am writing a small application that needs to communicate with a server using .NET Remoting. I am using AutoFac to register my instances and ran in to a problem when my remoting proxy object was being disposed, here is some sample code:

```
        builder.Register(b =>
        {
            var channel = new TcpClientChannel();
            // ...
            var remoteObj = (IMyComponent)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IMyComponent), "tcp://...");
            return remoteObj;
        }).As<IMyComponent>();

        // ... and then when using it:

        using (var scope = this.container.BeginLifetimeScope()) {

            var myComponent = scope.Resolve<IMyComponent>();

        } // <= An exception will be thrown here since AutoFac will try to call .Dispose on myComponent

        // Later I realized that the exception can be fixed by specifying an "empty" OnRealease-behavior when registering the component, probably because AutoFac doesnt try to treat MyComponent like an IDisposable.
        ...
        }).As<MyIComponent>().OnRelease(c => { //Manual disposing here });
```

This exception caused me to wonder if I am doing something completely wrong here and how to I am supposed to handle the lifetime of the remote proxy correctly. Is there anything wrong in my approach, ie to "create" and return remote proxys through AutoFac? If so, how should the lifetime of remote proxys be handled?

Answer (score 1):

[There are some detailed docs on how Autofac handles disposal on the Autofac doc site.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html) this may help clear up some of your questions.

If you have an `IDisposable` component on which you do not want Autofac to call `Dispose` for you, register it as `ExternallyOwned` and automatic disposal will be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ExternallyOwned will have the desired effect  (don't Dispose) in this particular example, although my question was really more about "methods for handling lifetime of remoting objects".